# How does multi-dimensional matrix indexing actually work under the hood?

Tags: python, pytorch

Hard to write that title, sorry.

I'm following a video and see that I can Index matrix C (below) with matrix X. But I don't understand the mechanic here. Given my lack of understanding, I tried to reproduce it with smaller matrices just to visualize it for myself...but I can't.

What is different about `C` and `X` matrices here vs `nums` and `indexers` matrices? In both cases, the sizes are different, the indexing matrix is larger than the one being indexed, and the values in the indexing matrix are different than those in the indexed matrix:

[image: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]

Comment: Please share code in text, not images.

Comment: Also, you mention tensors `C` and `X` but haven't shared their definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I think. The element values of the indexing matrix must be within the length of the dimension you're indexing in the matrix being indexed.

[image]

The `indexers` values will be used to index the row dimension of `nums`, which has a length of 2. That means indices (the values in the `indexers` matrix) must be 0 or 1, in this case.